How to Install and Use TVirtualStringTree in Delphi 12?
I'm trying to install and use the TVirtualStringTree component in Delphi 12 Community Edition, but I'm running into issues. I followed the installation steps provided in the documentation, but the IDE still cannot find the component. Here's what I did:

Opened the project group Packages\RAD Studio 10.4+\VirtualTreeView.groupproj.
Right-clicked on VirtualTreesD*.bpl and clicked "Install."
Went to Tools > Options > Language > Delphi Options > Library > Library Path > [...] and browsed to the "Source" folder of VirtualTreeView, then pressed "OK", "Add", and "OK".
Repeated this step for both the Win32 and Win64 platforms.
Closed the RAD Studio Options dialog by clicking "Save."

However, when I try to compile my project, I get the following error:
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(7): F2613 Unit 'VirtualTrees.BaseAncestorVCL' not found.


It seems like the IDE isn't recognizing the TVirtualStringTree component, even after following all the installation steps. How can I resolve this issue and properly install and use TVirtualStringTree in Delphi 12?
Additional Information:

I'm using Delphi 12 Community Edition on Windows 11.
I ensured that the paths were correctly set for both Win32 and Win64 platforms.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

All steps were necessary, and I have completed them, except for step 2, where the path should be included. After including the source path, it worked, and the IDE was able to find the components.

Your screen shot gives away your last name; you may want to update it.
